# Form view designer is not working in Visual Studio 2019 with C# .NET Core 3.1

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, .net-core

When I am opening a Visual Studio project with VB.NET then the Form view designer is automatically opened, but when I open a new project with C# .NET Core 3.1 with Windows Forms then it is showing code of *form1.cs*.

I tried to alternate from [Solution Explorer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#Other_tools) as well from menu *View* → *designer* option, but it is still not showing a form. What is going wrong there?

I made a Google search for this, but I did not find anything useful on this.

Please check in the image that I'm getting during the opening project.:

[image: Please check in the image that I'm getting during the opening project.]

Comment: Push `Shift+F7`, which is the shortcut to open the designer. You should also be able to access it using the Solution Explorer on the right-hand side of your VS environment.

Comment: I tried this as well but code is still there and form is not showing.

Comment: Are you sure you haven't picked a .Net Core 3 Windows Forms project instead of the .Net Framework one? Core 3 projects don't have the designer, yet.

Comment: The target framework is **.NET Core 3.0**

Comment: Yep, as already mentioned, you don't have a designer with .Net Core 3. You need the use .Net Framework template for now. You can try the preview version, if you want to test it: [Introducing .NET Core Windows Forms Designer Preview](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-net-core-windows-forms-designer-preview-1/)

Comment: Thank you so so much, **Jimi.**  I got what I'm doing wrong there. I forget to choose the framework option. There are two options. one Is the core and another is framework option. I must choose the **Windows forms App(.Net Framework)** Not a  **Windows forms App(.Net Core)**. That's why I am missing form because core 3 do not have a designer view form option as mentioned by **Jimi**.

Comment: This article mentions that it is only available for the preview version of Visual Studio 16.6 for .NET Core. https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/updates-on-net-core-windows-forms-designer/

Answer (score 28):

Make sure you only have the form declared in your file. If you have more than one class defined, the design viewer will not work.

Comment: This helped me, the designer worked fine until I added another class to the same file. It worked again when I removed the new class.

Comment: This was my issue. I had another class in the same file as Form1.cs. When I removed the class, the designer worked again.

Comment: Omg, what a nightmare that was. I created an EventArgs class in the same file as the control. VS should issue a warning or something about that. You saved me a LOT of time, no way I would have realized that on my own.

Comment: What a terribly designed IDE

Comment: OMG it is 2023 and they still haven't fixed this, so what if there is a non-Form class in the file, just look for public partial class SomeClass : Form

Answer (score 15):

Preview Visual Studio 2019 until v16.4 needs a VSIX separate installation extension. Now you can update your Preview of Visual Studio 2019 (to 16.5 or higher) and you don't need this extension. You can do it through the menu "Help" of the Visual Studio IDE.

After the update, go to menu *Tools* → *Options* → *Environment* → *Preview Features* and check the "Use previews of the .NET Core SDK (requires restart)" option.

Restart Visual Studio and it will work ;)

You can install the Preview Version that will have all these and more feature enabled. As it’s a preview, it may be unstable, but it can run side by side with your normal version in case something is broken in preview.

*[Visual Studio Preview](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/preview)*

Comment: Alternatively you can type `Preview Features` into the search anything box as opposed to navigating though the menu

Comment: I can confirm the issue still happens with vs2019 Community v16.5. Downloaded yesterday, created a form and today cannot open it. any attempt just open a second tab of the **form.cs** code

Comment: Downloaded the VSIX but it says it already installed. In addition, I still don't have that preview option

Comment: I am on v16.5.2 and still design view is not showing up.

Comment: You need to use Visual Studio **Preview** Channel

Comment: @PiotrKula what exactly does that mean please?

Comment: https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/preview/

Comment: In my case, I had one particular project where form designer didn't show up even though preview feature was enabled. I had tried VS 2019 and VS 2022 with no luck when I **created a new form** as an act of despair. After that designer just mysteriously initialized and started to work for all the forms within the project in both Visual Studios. Hope this info will save some nerves and time for someone.